# Why using ALLSELECTED() AND FILTER() together?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to understand the below DAX code:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Revenue[Net])
    ,FILTER('Center', NOT 'Center'[Acc] IN {"RSM", BLANK() })
    ,ALLSELECTED()
    ,VALUES('Customer'[Customer Number])
)
```

I have the below questions:

What's the use of **ALLSELECTED**?? By definition **ALLSELECTED** returns all rows in a table, ignoring any filters that might have been applied inside the query, but keeping filters that come from outside. https://dax.guide/allselected/

So, what's the point of writing **FILTER()** if its going to be forced to be ignored by the next line (ALLSELECTED)?!?

Also by definition:

[image]

CALCULATE is just a expresion followed by filters...

What's the use of VALUES() ? It doesn't appear to be a filter, so how is it even allowed to appear there? (Per definition VALUES(): ****returns a one-column table that contains the distinct values from the specified column**.**)

I do not understand what is this returning? is it the SUM() or the VALUES()?

(I come from a SQL background, so any sql-friendly answer is appreciated).

Comment: You may try to use one example to ask, from the formula you type, it cannot confirm if really working or there is better to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dax every filter is a table of values its look similar to INNER JOIN;
ALLSELECTED is useful when you need to keep a row context (this is also a filter in DAX). You can use ALLSELECTED inside FILTER function.

For better understand what engine does you can use a DaxStudio with ServerTiming;

[image]

As you see this product one simple statement:

```
SELECT
SUM ( 'Table'[Cost Centre] )
FROM 'Table'
WHERE
    'Table'[Project] NIN ( 'AB' ) ;
```

You can find useful article by Alberto Ferrari and Marco Russo:
https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/auto-exist-on-clusters-or-numbers-unplugged-22/

Comment: daxStudio translates every DAX to sql? That's great!!

Comment: I'm not sure if every, but for me, it's useful to know how the filter was managed. You can notice several queries because the engine works this way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only converting DAX queries if your connecting your sql analysis services to  in DAX studio. because it is not working for PBI file data

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32202899)